# Calling BTEQ from task scheduler

Tags: teradata

I created a .bteq script that looks like below:

.logmech LDAP;
.logon WM1/u0s000y,pwd;

SQL script here

.logoff;

And the above script is called in .bat file using below command:
BTEQ < Trial.bteq

But when i run this using windows task scheduler, it is throwing me a prompt asking me to select a program to run the BTEQ script. Looks like the scheduler does not know what program to use to run the BTEQ script.

What should I do to make the scheduler use teradata client for executing BTEQ script?

Thanks,

Comment: Is bteq in your path?  Maybe try fully qualifying the path to bteq in your schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Batch call should probably be:

```
type Trial.bteq | bteq
```

Comment: I resolved the issue. Tried using below command and it worked  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\Client\15.10\bin\bteq"<C:\Users\u0s000y\Desktop\Trial.bteq.      Specifying the BTEQ application path along with BTEQ script file.